# UFH reader Gen2 and tag G2iM+

Tags: rfid

I'm planning to build homemade UHF reader but I'm a little confused.

I've selected reader IC and tag IC.
The reader used EPC Gen2 communication protocol.
I really like NXP tag IC. But they use protocol UCODE G2iM+.
The problem is here. Are they compatible? I want to write from reader to the tag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the [page](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification_and_security/smart_label_and_tag_ics/ucode/series/SL3S1003_1013.html), "Key features: UHF RFID Gen2 tag chip according EPCglobal v1.2.0".  Also in the [datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SL3S1003_1013.pdf), search for "EPCglobal".